# setup an ftp server with mamp pro

Tags: apache, macos, ftp, mamp

I am currently using mamp pro on osx for local development and I want to mirror my mosso cloud setup as much as possible.  has anyone setup an ftp server with their local installation of mamp pro using sites i.e. local.mydev.com through apache?

hope everyone had a great holiday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heres how to do it: http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/08/how-to-access-ftp-with-mamp.html

found the instructions on Mamps site

Answer (score 0):

Not with MAMP Pro but I've done it with [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). It comes with proftpd which is a good ftp server. If you can switch, you might want to give XAMPP a try.

Comment: @ajitomatix - thank you for your reply man, I actually migrated from xampp to mamp pro, i found it worked better on osx imho, i wonder if I could integrate proftpd with mamp, shouldn't be too hard.  I really enjoy using mamp pro gui tools as well.  

I wonder what other mamp users are doing?

Comment: Most users have been using SSH for quite some time.